Angular how to access text from dynamically generated text fields
How can I access input field's data for the below angular code such that I can know for which label the field data is from.
<div *ngFor="let eachField of FieldList">
    <label>{{eachField}}</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder={{eachField}} (keyup)="GetData()" />
</div>

export class DisplayFiled {
    @Input() FieldList : Array<string> = ["Name", "Address", "Phone", "Email"];

    GetData(): void { 
       console.log("How to get the field's data for the label");
    }
}

Also what is the better approach for this type of dynamic elements.
EDIT:
I am trying the reactiveForms approach with table header
referring from the solution provided -
<table>
    <tr>
        <form [formGroup]="form">
            <div *ngFor="let eachField of DisplayColumns">
                <label>{{eachField.DisplayName}}</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder={{eachField.DisplayName}} [formControlName]="eachField.Property"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>

I see that the same thing can be rendered with div but when I put in inside a table header it does not work.

We can use ReactiveForms to create these dynamic elements, on load, we loop through the array and create each FormControl for all the elements of the array.
Then after the controls are added to the object, we assign that object to the formGroup and then we can access the properties using value.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div *ngFor="let eachField of FieldList">
          <label>{{eachField}}</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder={{eachField}} [formControlName]="eachField"/>
      </div>
  </form>

  {{form.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  @Input() FieldList: Array<string> = ['Name', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Email'];
  form = new FormGroup({});

  ngOnInit() {
    const formGroupStr: any = {};
    this.FieldList.forEach((controlName: string) => {
      formGroupStr[controlName] = new FormControl('');
    });
    this.form = new FormGroup(formGroupStr);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for the answer. I have slightly updated the question, can you please help me with this.

@RahulChakrabarty like this stackblitz ?
